# Open api generator does not generate enum for reusable enum

Tags: java, android, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Is have a open api yaml:

```
ParentPlanState:
  type: string
  enum:
    - NOT_PLANNABLE
    - PLANNABLE
    - REQUEST_EXTRA_DAY
    - REQUEST_EXTRA_DAY_DURING_HOLIDAY
```

Is used in other object like:

planState:
$ref: '#/ParentPlanState'

When it's not a reusable enum. I get an enum. But not when i define is like this.

This is generated: (android)

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ApiModel(
    description = ""
)
public class ParentPlanState implements Serializable {
    public ParentPlanState() {
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        } else if (o != null && this.getClass() == o.getClass()) {
            ParentPlanState parentPlanState = (ParentPlanState)o;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("class ParentPlanState {\n");
        sb.append("}\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This is what i was expecting: (From  jaxrs-resteasy-eap)

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import java.io.Serializable;
public enum ParentPlanState {
  NOT_PLANNABLE,
  PLANNABLE,
  REQUEST_EXTRA_DAY,
  REQUEST_EXTRA_DAY_DURING_HOLIDAY;
}
```

Anybody any idea's. Open api spec 3.0.3

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you get any info on that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I was facing the same issue I created a template mustache named model.mustache to overwrite the original one.
The main problem is that the `#isEnum` condition always return false but `^isEnum` is working correctly; so I found a way to check for `enum` differently with `#allowableValues`. The solution consist to create two generation block one for `enum` and the second one for `model`.

This is what you must do step by step.

1. Create a new file in your project called model.mustache
2. Add the following content to the file:

```html
package {{package}};

{{#imports}}import {{import}};
{{/imports}}

import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
{{#models}}
    {{#model}}
        {{#allowableValues}}

            @ApiModel(description = "")
            public enum {{classname}} {
            {{#allowableValues}}{{#values}} {{.}}, {{/values}}{{/allowableValues}}
            }
        {{/allowableValues}}
    {{/model}}
{{/models}}

{{#models}}

    {{#model}}
        {{^isEnum}}
{{#description}}
        /**

        {{.}}
        **/{{/description}}
    @ApiModel(description = "{{{description}}}")
    public class {{classname}} {{#parent}}extends {{{.}}}{{/parent}} {
    {{#vars}}{{#isEnum}}
        public enum {{datatypeWithEnum}} {
        {{#allowableValues}}{{#values}} {{.}}, {{/values}}{{/allowableValues}}
        };
        @SerializedName("{{baseName}}")
        private {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}} = {{{defaultValue}}};{{/isEnum}}{{^isEnum}}
        @SerializedName("{{baseName}}")
        private {{{dataType}}} {{name}} = {{{defaultValue}}};{{/isEnum}}{{/vars}}

    {{#vars}}
        /**{{#description}}

            {{{.}}}{{/description}}{{#minimum}}
            minimum: {{.}}{{/minimum}}{{#maximum}}
            maximum: {{.}}{{/maximum}}
        **/
        @ApiModelProperty({{#required}}required = {{required}}, {{/required}}value = "{{{description}}}")
        public {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{getter}}() {
        return {{name}};
        }
        public void {{setter}}({{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}) {
        this.{{name}} = {{name}};
        }

    {{/vars}}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
    return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
    return false;
    }
    {{classname}} {{classVarName}} = ({{classname}}) o;{{#hasVars}}
        return {{#vars}}(this.{{name}} == null ? {{classVarName}}.{{name}} == null : this.{{name}}.equals({{classVarName}}.{{name}})){{^-last}} &&
        {{/-last}}{{#-last}};{{/-last}}{{/vars}}{{/hasVars}}{{^hasVars}}
        return true;{{/hasVars}}
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    {{#vars}}
        result = 31 * result + (this.{{name}} == null ? 0: this.{{name}}.hashCode());
    {{/vars}}
    return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class {{classname}} {\n");
    {{#parent}}sb.append(" " + super.toString()).append("\n");{{/parent}}
    {{#vars}}sb.append(" {{name}}: ").append({{name}}).append("\n");
    {{/vars}}sb.append("}\n");
    return sb.toString();
    }
    }
    {{/isEnum}}
    {{/model}}
{{/models}}
```

3. Now in your generating configuration, you mus add the template folder path with `templateDir = "path/to/the/folder/were/you/create/model.mustache"`

This is and example of the config I have in my `build.gradle`

```
var generatedSourcesPath = "$buildDir" // /generated/sources/openapi
var apiDescriptionFolder = "$rootDir/app/openapi"
var apiRootName = "com.deepdrimz.openapi"

ext {
    sName = 'njangui'
}
openApiGenerate {
    var serviceName = findProperty("sName")
    generatorName = "android"
    templateDir = "${apiDescriptionFolder}/templates"
    inputSpec = "${apiDescriptionFolder}/${serviceName}.yaml"
    outputDir = "${generatedSourcesPath}"
    modelPackage = "${apiRootName}.${serviceName}"
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8",
        library: "httpclient",
        serializationLibrary: "gson",
        serializableModel   : "true"
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).