# Enums are not getting Generated in OpenApI 3.0?

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Iam trying of to generate the swagger beans from open API tool when i upgraded openApi version, it is not generating the ENUMS for swagger beans.

My issue is similar to [Open api generator does not generate enum for reusable enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76707565/open-api-generator-does-not-generate-enum-for-reusable-enum)

Any help is much appreciated

Iam trying of to generate the swagger beans from open API tool when i upgraded openApi version, it is not generating the ENUMS for swagger beans.